# Where did music scan go on my iOS 4.2 iPod Touch 2nd Gen?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

A week ago, I had a slider when playing music that let me scan through music really quickly. Now it's gone. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Did I change a setting or something? I can't find anything about it. The slider used to be near the top. I only have the standard fast-forward/rewind buttons now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried tapping the album art while the music or podcast is playing? That should bring the "scrub-bar" to the screen where you can quickly scan through the media currently playing (seek-bar at the top of the picture).

[image: scrub-bar]